# How to loop this javascript object?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, just simple code, but basically I want this to automatically back to the right and loop again (From right to left, at the right side of the window it showed in the left side again) right now this code only make the object infinitely move from left to right
Is it possible?

```js
var imgObj = null;
var animate;

function init() {
  imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
  imgObj.style.position = 'relative';
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

function moveRight() {
  imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
  animate = setTimeout(moveRight, 20); // call moveRight in 20msec
}

function stop() {
  clearTimeout(animate);
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Animation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <img id="myImage" src="/images/html.gif" />
    <p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight();" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop();" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When your left position is greater than the width of the window you need to reset it back to zero to make it come on the left side.

Comment: how to reset and how to  define my window width? can you give me example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your image is past the width the of the window, it needs to have its position reset to zero. You can do this with the modulus operator.

```js
var imgObj = null;
var animate;

function init() {
  imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
  imgObj.style.position = 'relative';
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

function moveRight() {
  var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  var newLeft = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10
  imgObj.style.left = newLeft % bodyWidth + 'px';
  animate = setTimeout(moveRight, 20); // call moveRight in 20msec
}

function stop() {
  clearTimeout(animate);
  imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>JavaScript Animation</title>



</head>

<body>

  <form>
    <img id="myImage" src="/images/html.gif" />
    <p>Click the buttons below to handle animation</p>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="moveRight();" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop" onclick="stop();" />
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```